# What is the subject of a participial phrase?

Tags: meaning-in-context, participial-phrases

> But the hand which I now saw, clearly enough, in the yellow light of a
> mid-London morning, lying half shut on the bedclothes, was lean,
> corded, knuckly, of a dusky pallor and thickly shaded with a swart
> growth of hair.

This is from the classic novel Strange Case of Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde. I wonder what was lying half shut on the bedclothes. Was it a hand or speaker itself?

Comment: 'Lying half closed' would be the idiomatic expression. 'Closure' is different from 'shutting'. We talk about an 'open palm' but a 'closed hand'. Different concepts.

Comment: The subject is "the hand which I now saw".

Answer (score 1):

It was the hand.

There is technically some ambiguity, but we do not talk of people *lying half shut*, or for that matter parts of the day - *a mid-London morning* might just as well have been modified by *lying half shut*.

Comment: I'd go for "the hand which I now saw".